# Regex to match varying strings in a list

Tags: python, regex

I have a Python list containing unicode strings:

```
mylist = [
  u'Path:path\\to\\some\\file.html\n   user ID: a.b.c\n',
  u'Path:somewhat\\longer\\path\\to\\some\\file.jpeg\n   user ID: a:b_c\n    someotherID:x:x:x\n'
]
```

I need to extract only the last part of Path: in this case file.html and file.jpeg. Is there any comprehensive regex to get this information out of my list?

Comment: Don't you mean `file.jpeg` in stead of `file.img`?

Comment: or `[re.match(r'(?m)Path:.*\\([^\\\n]*)$', i).group(1) for i in mylist]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `ntpath` instead of `os.path` you get proper behaviour without shaky regexes:

```
>>> import ntpath
>>> [ntpath.basename(entry.split('\n')[0]) for entry in mylist]
[u'file.html', u'file.jpeg']
```

Contrary to what @Kasra says, your paths are valid, they just come from another operating system.

Comment: This works perfectly well but is there a regex that can do the same?

Comment: @Tania Yes and no. Could you write a regex to do this correctly? Yes. Is it a good idea to do so? No, I don't think so. If you write a regex, you write code specifically to deal with this particular problem you have right now. If something about the path changes down the line, your regex might not deal with that. By using basename, your code will keep working as long as you run it on paths.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need regex you can use [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename), but first you need to replace `\` with `/` then use `path.basename` :

```
>>> from os import path
>>> [path.basename(i.split()[0].replace('\\','/')) for i in mylist if i]
[u'file.html', u'file.jpeg']
```

Comment: My paths are valid @Kasra. They just come from a different os. In fact they are unicode strings and are delimited like path\\to\\whatever\\

Comment: @Tania Yeah, i got it! ;)

Comment: Thank you. But this solution doesn't work when an extra empty field came into the list. Throws an index out of range exception

Comment: @Tania Try using regex as seen in my answer.

Comment: @Tania Welcome , so you need to check for `i` within your loop! checkout the edit!

Comment: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'basename'

Answer (score 1):

```
for path in path_list:
    # assuming each item in the list actually contains a path
    print re.search(r'Path:(?:.*?\\)(\w+\.\w+)', path).group(1)
```

Comment: Thanks Malik this one works too. Thanks for the awesome regex.

Comment: Any time, I'm glad I could help.